# Can i buy a domain and create a custom email for another email serivice?

Tags: email, domain

Can I buy a domain from example Namecheap, then use mx record and use a free email hosting like google Gmail? or am I obligated to buy email hosting and pay more?
Namecheap offer email hosting that cost more, but is this necessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few minutes of research will show you that Google will, in fact, allow you to use their mail to host email for your domain... for a price, which I seem to recall is US$2 per address per month.

Comment: that is not my question, i am asking if i can use the google gmail using only a domain from other provider, without paying per address because u already have the domain. for example you buy @adress.com from namecheap and then on mxrecord use it to forward to a gmail address. without paying email host?

Comment: If you want to receive mail as grg@grgdomain.com, with gmail as the mail server, you pay Google for the use of their server and storage. If you point mx -> googlemail.com, google will drop it because they aren't set to receive grgdomain.com mail.

Comment: and there is some free mail that receive mail from a custom domain? in the case of google i would need to pay them for redirect from my domain

Comment: I'm unaware of any, and I honestly wouldn't expect there to be any, because somehow that service and storage has to be paid for. Ad revenue goes only so far.

Comment: Thanks you for answer!